# How to avoid creating new byte arrays for each invocation of a WCF operation method?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, wcf, f#

Is there a way to avoid creating new byte array instances with fixed lengths and calling `Array.Copy` from the larger byte array `Buffer` to the newly created reply array called `reply`?

- Change the API of the WCF Host!?
- Use a to-me-unbeknownst method that creates an Array-looking-&-behaving view onto another array?

Or any other ideas?

```
// Buffer : byte[]
// host : a WCF host
while (code >= 0)
{
    try
    {
        if (Socket.Available == 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(Wait);
            continue;
        }

        var length = Socket.Receive(Buffer);
        if (length > 0)
        {
            Log("Read", ServerPort, " ->", Client, length);

            var reply = new byte[length];
            Array.Copy(Buffer, reply, length);

            try { code = host.Reply(ServerPort, Client, reply); }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                code = -2;
                Log("Exception", ServerPort, "<=>", Client, ex);
                ConnectToHost();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        code = -3;
        Delist();
        if (ex.GetType() != typeof(ThreadAbortException))
            Log("Exception", ServerPort, "!!!", Client, ex);

        Log("Disconnect", ServerPort, @"<\>", Client, Relay.Host.Address());
        Tcp.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ArraySegment<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) as a way to pass around pieces of a larger byte array. I think the API is kinda crappy, but it certainly does the trick.

However, seems like you'd probably also benefit from using the [BufferManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.buffermanager.aspx) class provided for WCF for managing reusable buffers in your code.

Comment: I have a feeling WCF might not know how to marshal ArraySegment<byte> instances over the wire. BufferManager sounds a like neat replacement for newing short reply arrays up each time.